# Merging array elements in multidimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've a php array like below

```
Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
            [0] => Some name 
            [1] => some email 
            [2] => 17981 
            [3] => 0 
            [4] => 52 
            [5] => a 
            [6] => b 
            [7] => c 
            [8] => d
        )
)
```

I would like to merge the elements of the array after 5th index so "a,b,c,d" combine into single index like below

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Some name 
        [1] => some email 
        [2] => 17981 
        [3] => 0 
        [4] => 52 
        [5] =>a,b,c,d 
    )
)
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Could you please share some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add foreach and pass arry in it.
then you need to add condition inside foreach to check whether element index is  > 4 if yes then append its value to 5th element else do nothing.

example code :

```
          foreach ($origArray as $key => $subArray)

          $subArray += $arrayToBeAdded[$key];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the input array and accept all entries into your output array how you want them to be placed:

```
<?php
$input = [["Some name", "some email", 17981, 0, 52, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']];
$output = [];
$divider = 5;
array_walk($input[0], function($entry, $key) use (&$output, $divider) {
  if ($key < $divider) {
    $output[0][] = $entry;
  } else {
    $output[0][$divider][] = $entry;
  }
});
print_r($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some name
            [1] => some email
            [2] => 17981
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 52
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
                    [2] => c
                    [3] => d
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this,it works for single index array as i asked. 

But I should have mentioned that array will be multilevel and not only single index

Right now if i use your solution on array like below , adding it in new comment due to characters limit

Comment: ```Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
            [0] => Some name 
            [1] => some email 
            [2] => 17981 
            [3] => 0 
            [4] => 52 
            [5] => a 
            [6] => b 
            [7] => c 
            [8] => d
        ),
Array ( 
      [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => Some name 
            [1] => some email 
            [2] => 17981 
            [3] => 0 
            [4] => 52 
            [5] => e 
            [6] => f 
            [7] => g 
            [8] => h
        ),

))```

continuing the result on next comment

Comment: ``Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Some name 
        [1] => some email 
        [2] => 17981 
        [3] => 0 
        [4] => 52 
        [5] =>a,b,c,d
    )
)```

the desire output it below

```Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Some name 
        [1] => some email 
        [2] => 17981 
        [3] => 0 
        [4] => 52 
        [5] =>a,b,c,d 
    ),
  [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => Some name 
        [1] => some email 
        [2] => 17981 
        [3] => 0 
        [4] => 52 
        [5] =>e,f,g,h
    ))```

Comment: That structure _really_ is a strange one. I would suggest you first clean up your input data to a structure that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

You can slide your array into 2, then use implode to glue the second half:

```
$input = [["Some name", "some email", 17981, 0, 52, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']];

$array = $input[0];

$firstArray = array_slice($array, 0, 5); //return ["Some name", "some email", 17981, 0, 52]
$secondArray = array_slice($array, 5); //return ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

$firstArray[] = implode(",",$secondArray);

$input[0] = $firstArray;

print_r($input);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some name
            [1] => some email
            [2] => 17981
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 52
            [5] => a,b,c,d
        )

)
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/c45KS